# HSL color picker: background color not changing

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker, hsl

I am creating an HSL color picker [here](https://codepen.io/EmojiMaker/pen/jOrRvdB), and so far I have only done hue and saturation. I am trying to change the background color of the body when the value of one of the `<input type="range>`'s changes, and I don't know what's happening, but the background color is not changing. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hsl values of saturation and lightness should be in percentage. change the line in your interval to:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${hue},${saturation}%,${lightness}%)`
```

That should work.